# Removing minor mode name from showing in emacs buffer window

Tags: minor-mode

How can I remove a minor mode name from the buffer window menu located at the window bottom.  More useful, is there a way to include or exclude the minor mode name in the buffer window by just calling a command, e.g. `(include-name 'feature 'menu)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a heap of packages for doing this in various ways.

Options I'm aware of are:

- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelightedModes
- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiminishedModes
- https://github.com/alezost/dim.el
- https://github.com/Malabarba/rich-minority
- https://github.com/radian-software/blackout
- https://github.com/tarsius/minions
- https://github.com/mrkkrp/cyphejor

Comment: Thank you.  Which are the easier to start with?

Comment: I'm biased because I wrote the first one in that list (initially because I was dissatisfied with the second one, which seemed to be the go-to at that time, but was annoying to configure).  I think the rest are all newer, written by other people scratching their own versions of this itch.  FWIW I think mine works well and has good documentation, so I can suggest starting with that and seeing how you get on.

Comment: Will start with that.  After all you would know its details more than anybody else in case I encounter some difficulty.